# Dynamic Button in WPF DataGrid - CellTemplateSelector

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, celltemplate

I have a datagrid in which I want to add a button to each line. This button should have another function depending on a condition.
The datagrid consists of a list of some files that can be installed or, if already present, uninstalled using the button. Therefore the button should be called either "Install" or "Uninstall".

I created the following xaml

```xml
...
<Grid.Resources>            
    <local:ButtonTemplateSelector x:Key="buttonTemplateSelector">
        <local:ButtonTemplateSelector.InstallButtonTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button x:Name="btn_installSnippet" Click="btn_installSnippet_Click">Install</Button>
        </DataTemplate>
        </local:ButtonTemplateSelector.InstallButtonTemplate>
        <local:ButtonTemplateSelector.UninstallButtonTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button x:Name="btn_uninstallSnippet" Click="btn_uninstallSnippet_Click">Uninstall</Button>
        </DataTemplate>
            </local:ButtonTemplateSelector.UninstallButtonTemplate>
    </local:ButtonTemplateSelector>
</Grid.Resources>
...
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid_newViews" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="148" Margin="40,152,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="685" AutoGenerateColumns="True" SelectedCellsChanged="Datagrid_SelectedCellsChanged" CanUserAddRows="false" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Button" CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource buttonTemplateSelector}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

In my main code, I have created the following:

```cs
public class ButtonTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate InstallButtonTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate UninstallButtonTemplate { get; set; }

    public override System.Windows.DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, System.Windows.DependencyObject container)
    {
      return InstallButtonTemplate;
    }
}
```

Here I am completely stuck, on how to get a value from the row (from datagrid binding), to write the condition if `InstallButtonTemplate` or `UninstallButtonTemplate` should be returned.

Comment: You should look at `item` parameter, cast to type, which is bound to data grid rows and check it's properties

Answer (score 0):

You have pretty much done all the work, one piece that is missing is to cast your `object item` parameter to the data type of the item in the collection you are binding to like this:

```
public class ButtonTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate InstallButtonTemplate { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate UninstallButtonTemplate { get; set; }

    public override System.Windows.DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, System.Windows.DependencyObject container)
    {
      var myItem = (YourType)item;
      if (myItem.FilePresent == true){
         return UninstallButtonTemplate ;
      }
      return InstallButtonTemplate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I do understand what you mean, but unfortunately I do not get any properties of the casted object item yet. I will try on...